# Stanford NLP NER Time tag not working

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

My input sentence is this `Let's meet on wednesday at 9:00AM.`  Now while checking the NER tagging with `classifier` `english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz` here http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process I am getting perfect tagging for `wednesday` as `Date` and `9:00AM` for `Time`.

But when I am checking the same in my python application below code snippet

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
text="Let's meet on wednesday at 09:00am."
tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)
print(classified_text)
```

Its tagging `9:00AM` as `O` .Here is the complete o/p

```
[('Let', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('meet', 'O'), ('on', 'O'), ('wednesday', 'DATE'), ('at', 'O'), ('09:00am', 'O'), ('.', 'O')]
```